# How do I make elements a percentage width in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, nslayoutconstraint

I am new to `Xcode`, previously developed apps as hybrid so decided to learn `swift`. The language itself is easy to learn, I code in many languages. But I am not understanding why `Xcode` doesn't let me use percentage widths on things!

The first screenshot shows 4 buttons next to each other on `iPhone 8 plus`, but the second screenshot is when I change to `iPad`, you can see that the boxes don't resize to fit.

It doesn't allow me to enter percentage (`25%`) of the view so how am I supposed to make them all fit on difference devices? I know about constraints but I can't figure out what constrains it needs to a) Make them all stay `25%` of the view b) So they sit next to each other and just resize.

[image]

[image]

After trying the accepted answer it worked, but when I try to add a second row doing the same thing the following happens:

**Setting constraints for first row:**

[image]

**Setting constraints for second row:**

[image]

**The result:**

[image]

Why did it work for the first row but not the second?

Comment: You can set an aspect ratio constraint of 4:1 between the view width and the first button width. Then create constraints that make each of the other buttons equal to the first.

Comment: That can be achieved using UIStackView with autolayout. Read about AutoLayout and about StackView's and you will learn how to set the UI properly.

Comment: Remove tickmark `Contraint to margins` and reset all constraints

Comment: Ok will try that thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add all buttons in a single container view. Assign equal width constraint to all button with no spacing with each other (adjacent view/button) and superview.

**Try this and see:**

[image]

**Here is result in iPhone 4s and 8+ preview:**

[image]

**Result for iPad:**

[image]

Comment: only problem is, if I try to do exactly the same thing again but have a row at the bottom it doesn't work

Comment: Could you share your code/interface file, so I can see, what exactly you are doing and where is still issue? I'll surely solve all your problem regarding this interface design.

Comment: I edited my question above with screenshots after following your instructions. First row it worked, but then when trying to do the same thing on a second row of buttons it leaves a white gap left and right. Then if I try to drag them all to the bottom and then change the device the scaling stops working and they don't stick to the bottom. Maybe I should read more on constraints!

Comment: Check the smae in iPad and let me know, what is result?

Comment: Same result on all devices

Comment: Share here screenshot for iPad.  
Remove tickmark `Contraint to margins` and reset all constraints.

Comment: For "Equal Width" and "Aspect ratio" check this page: https://jascode.wordpress.com/2019/08/15/weight-assignment-in-stack-viewpercentage-wise-size-calculation/

Answer (score 1):

You must set each button's width equal to superview's width and set constrain's multiplier to 0.25[image]